# limit of $ \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}-2}{e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}+2} $ as $x$ goes to $1$

Tags: calculus, limits

limit of $ \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}-2}{e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}+2} $ as $x \to 1$. I attempted to solve it by dividing both the numerator and denominator by $e^{1/x-1}$
however wolfram says $1$ is wrong.It says the limit doesn't exist,why is that?

Comment: Isn't the function constantly $1$?

Comment: my bad, I meant +2 , not -2

Comment: Isn't continuous in $x=0$?

Comment: yes, but algebraically. I'm unable to understand why that's the case

Comment: The limit exists... the function is (obviously) continuous at $x=0.$ Either you used WolframAlpha incorrectly or the function you posted is not the one in question.

Comment: There is no indeterminate form, $f$ is continuous in $x=0$ because is a composition of continuous functions in $x=0$. Maybe the limit is as $x \to 1$(?)

Comment: yes, I did. I'm sorry

Comment: The title says $x$ goes to $1$, but the question says $x$ tends to $0$. Which is it?

Comment: 1, my bad...........

Answer (score 2):

Consider $x \to 1^+$
$$\lim_{x \to 1^+}\dfrac{e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}-2}{e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}+2}=\lim_{t \to 0^+}\dfrac{e^{\frac{1}{t}}-2}{e^{\frac{1}{t}}+2}=\lim_{s \to +\infty}\dfrac{e^s-2}{e^s+2}=1$$
If $x \to 1^-$
$$\lim_{x \to 1^-}\dfrac{e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}-2}{e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}+2}=\lim_{t \to 0^-}\dfrac{e^{\frac{1}{t}}-2}{e^{\frac{1}{t}}+2}=\lim_{s \to -\infty}\dfrac{e^s-2}{e^s+2}=-1$$
Hence two-sided limit does not exist.

Comment: I see, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The function $e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}$ is continuous except at $x=1$. Therefore, at $0$, both $e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}-2$ and $e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}+2$ are continuous. Since $e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}+2>0$, their fraction is continuous. Therefore:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}-2}{e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}+2} = \frac{e^{-1}-2}{e^{-1}+2}
$$